# Ao tentar gerar relatório me deparo com este erro! Estou utilizando Jasper

Tags: java, jsf, spring, jasper

Estou utilizando um composite para fazer impressão dos relatórios 
Obs: consigo emitir o relatorio com minha Cidade normalmente o problema é com o material.

```html
Menu Impressão Composite

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
 xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/facelets/tags"
 xmlns:util="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/componentes"
 xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
 
 <composite:interface>
  <composite:attribute name="bean" required="true"/>
 </composite:interface>
 
 <composite:implementation>
  
    <h:commandLink  immediate="true">
  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="1" target="#{cc.attrs.bean.tipoRelatorio}"/>
   <p:fileDownload value="#{cc.attrs.bean.arquivoReport}"/>
   <h:graphicImage library="img" name="pdf.png"/>
  </h:commandLink>
  
  <h:commandLink  immediate="true">
  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="2" target="#{cc.attrs.bean.tipoRelatorio}"/>
   <p:fileDownload value="#{cc.attrs.bean.arquivoReport}"/>
   <h:graphicImage library="img" name="excel.png"/>
  </h:commandLink>
  
  <h:commandLink  immediate="true">
  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="3" target="#{cc.attrs.bean.tipoRelatorio}"/>
   <p:fileDownload value="#{cc.attrs.bean.arquivoReport}"/>
   <h:graphicImage library="img" name="html.png"/>
  </h:commandLink>
  
  <h:commandLink  immediate="true">
  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="4" target="#{cc.attrs.bean.tipoRelatorio}"/>
   <p:fileDownload value="#{cc.attrs.bean.arquivoReport}"/>
   <h:graphicImage library="img" name="ods.png"/>
  </h:commandLink>
  
  
 </composite:implementation>
 
</html>
```

```html
Cadastro de Material

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
 xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/facelets/tags"
 xmlns:util="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/componentes"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="/templates/templatePrincipal.xhtml" >
  <ui:define name="corpo">
  
  <!-- Cadastro de MATERIAL FORM -->
  <h:form id="formCadastro" prependId="false">
   <c:set var="isCadastro" value="true" scope="view" />
   <br/>
   
   <p:panel header="Cadastro de Material" id="panelCadastro" styleClass="tamanhoDosPanels">
    <h:panelGrid id="gridCidade" columns="3">
     
     <!-- Label Código -->
     <h:outputLabel for="id" value="Código: " id="labelId" />
     
     <!-- Input Código -->
     <p:inputText id="id" styleClass="estiloIdCadastro" disabled="true"
      value="#{materialBeanView.objetoSelecionado.idMaterial}" />
     
     <!-- Alinhamento um 3º Campo -->
     <h:outputLabel />
     
     <!-- Label Nome da Material -->
     <h:outputLabel id="labelNomeConsultaMaterial" for="materialNome"
      value="Nome * :" />
     
     <!-- Input Nome da Material -->
     <p:inputText id="materialNome" styleClass="estiloInputNome"
      required="true" maxlength="100"
      value="#{materialBeanView.objetoSelecionado.nomeMaterial}"
      requiredMessage="Informe o nome do material" />
     
     <!-- Redirecionar Mensagem do Erro -->
     <p:message for="materialNome" id="materialNomeMessageError" />
     
     <!-- Label Quantidade -->
     <h:outputLabel for="quantidadeMaterial" id="labelQuantidadeMaterial" value="Quantidade * :" />
     
     <p:inputText id="quantidadeMaterial" rendered="true"
      requiredMessage="Informe a quantidade do material"
      value="#{materialBeanView.objetoSelecionado.quantidade}"/>
     
     <!-- Redirecionar Mensagem do Erro -->
     <p:message for="quantidadeMaterial" id="materialQuantidadeMessageError"  />
     
     <!-- Label Valor Unitario -->
     <h:outputLabel for="valorUnitario" id="labelValorUnitario" value="Valor Unitário * :" />
     
     <p:inputText id="valorUnitario" rendered="true"
      requiredMessage="Informe a valor do material"
      value="#{materialBeanView.objetoSelecionado.valorUnitario}"/>
     
     <!-- Redirecionar Mensagem do Erro -->
     <p:message for="valorUnitario" id="materialValorUnitarioMessageError"  />
     
     
    </h:panelGrid>
   </p:panel>

   <div class="espacoBranco" />
   
   <!-- Chama Botões  Recarrega Template growl messages e tabela de resultados-->
   <util:botoesCrud 
      managedBeanView="#{materialBeanView}"
      camposReload=":formTemplate:msg, tableResult" 
      botaoNovo="#{contextoBean.possuiAcesso('CIDADE_NOVO', 'ADMIN')}"
      botaoSalvar="#{contextoBean.possuiAcesso('CIDADE_NOVO', 'ADMIN')
      and materialBeanView.objetoSelecionado.idMaterial == null}"
      botaoAtualizar ="#{contextoBean.possuiAcesso('ACESSO_EDITAR', 'ADMIN') 
      and materialBeanView.objetoSelecionado.idMaterial != null}"
      botaoRedirecionar ="#{contextoBean.possuiAcesso('ACESSO_EDITAR', 'ADMIN')}" 
      >
   </util:botoesCrud>
      
   
  </h:form>
  
  <!-- JavaScript de Foco no Nome da Cidade e Configuração do Enter  -->
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
   addFocoCampo("materialNome");
   gerenciaTeclaEnter();
  </script>
  
  <!-- Espaço entre FORM e LISTA -->
  <div class="espacoBranco"/>
  <p:panel styleClass="tamanhoDosPanels">
  <!-- Lista de Material DataTable -->
  <p:dataTable id="tableResult" value="#{materialBeanView.list.list}" style="background-color: #d7e7f9; border: none;border-style: hidden"
   var="objeto" emptyMessage="Não existem valores para exibição" 
   rows="20" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" 
   paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink}
         {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks}
         {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} 
         {RowsPerPageDropdown} ">
         
  <ui:include src="/resources/componentes/colunasDataTableMaterial.xhtml"/>       
  </p:dataTable>
  </p:panel>
 </ui:define>
</ui:composition>

</html>
```

```html
ADVERTÊNCIA: /resources/componentes/menuImpressao.xhtml @20,60 value="#{cc.attrs.bean.arquivoReport}": Error reading 'arquivoReport' on type br.com.projeto.bean.view.MaterialBeanView javax.el.ELException: /resources/componentes/menuImpressao.xhtml @20,60
value="#{cc.attrs.bean.arquivoReport}": Error reading 'arquivoReport' on type br.com.projeto.bean.view.MaterialBeanView at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114) at org.primefaces.component.filedownload.FileDownloadActionListener.processAction(FileDownloadActionListener.java:53)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88) at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813) at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300) at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931) at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78) at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at br.com.projeto.filter.FilterOpenSessionInView.doFilter(FilterOpenSessionInView.java:72) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) at
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Error reading
'arquivoReport' on type br.com.projeto.bean.view.MaterialBeanView at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:110) at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116) at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163) at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219) at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeValueExpression.getValue(ContextualCompositeValueExpression.java:158)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) ... 71 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilationFailedException at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585) at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2885) at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1723) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getCompiler(JasperCompileManager.java:814)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getEvaluator(JasperCompileManager.java:377) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createCalculator(JRFillDataset.java:462) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.
<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:405) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.
  <init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:89) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.
    <init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:104) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.
      <init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:62) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:179) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:108) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:668)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:984) at br.com.projeto.report.util.ReportUtil.geraRelatorio(ReportUtil.java:115) at br.com.projeto.report.util.BeanReportView.getArquivoReport(BeanReportView.java:44)
        at br.com.projeto.bean.view.MaterialBeanView.getArquivoReport(MaterialBeanView.java:44) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:99) ... 78 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationFailedException at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1858)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701) ... 101 more
```

```js
Minha Model
package br.com.projeto.model.classes;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;

import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

import br.com.projeto.anotacoes.IdentificaCampoPesquisa;

@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "material")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "material_seq", sequenceName = "material_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
public class Material implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;

  @IdentificaCampoPesquisa(descricaoCampo = "Código", campoConsulta = "idMaterial", principal = 1)
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "material_seq")

  private Long idMaterial;
  @IdentificaCampoPesquisa(descricaoCampo = "Nome", campoConsulta = "nomeMaterial", principal = 2)
  private String nomeMaterial;

  private int quantidade;

  private Double valorUnitario;

  @Version
  @Column(name = "versionNum")
  private int versionNum;

  //EQUALS E HASCODE

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((idMaterial == null) ? 0 : idMaterial.hashCode());
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
      return true;
    if (obj == null)
      return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
    Material other = (Material) obj;
    if (idMaterial == null) {
      if (other.idMaterial != null)
        return false;
    } else if (!idMaterial.equals(other.idMaterial))
      return false;
    return true;
  }

  //GETTERS E SETTERS
  public Long getIdMaterial() {
    return idMaterial;
  }

  public void setIdMaterial(Long idMaterial) {
    this.idMaterial = idMaterial;
  }

  public String getNomeMaterial() {
    return nomeMaterial;
  }

  public void setNomeMaterial(String nomeMaterial) {
    this.nomeMaterial = nomeMaterial;
  }

  public int getQuantidade() {
    return quantidade;
  }

  public void setQuantidade(int quantidade) {
    this.quantidade = quantidade;
  }

  public Double getValorUnitario() {
    return valorUnitario;
  }

  public void setValorUnitario(Double valorUnitario) {
    this.valorUnitario = valorUnitario;
  }

  public int getVersionNum() {
    return versionNum;
  }

  public void setVersionNum(int versionNum) {
    this.versionNum = versionNum;
  }


  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Material [idMaterial=" + idMaterial + ", nomeMaterial=" + nomeMaterial + ", quantidade=" + quantidade +
      ", valorUnitario=" + valorUnitario + "]";
  }


}
```

```html
Meu ManagedBean

package br.com.projeto.bean.view;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import br.com.framework.inteface.crud.InterfaceCrud;
import br.com.projeto.bean.geral.BeanManagedViewAbstract;
import br.com.projeto.carregamento.lazy.CarregamentoLazyListForObjeto;
import br.com.projeto.geral.controller.MaterialController;
import br.com.projeto.model.classes.Material;


@Controller
@Scope(value = "session")
@ManagedBean(name = "materialBeanView")
public class MaterialBeanView extends BeanManagedViewAbstract {
 
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
 private Material objetoSelecionado = new Material();
 
 private String url = "/cadastro/cad_material.jsf?faces-redirect=true";
 private String urlFind = "/cadastro/find_material.jsf?faces-redirect=true";
 
 private CarregamentoLazyListForObjeto<Material> list = new CarregamentoLazyListForObjeto<Material>();
  
 @Autowired
 private MaterialController materialController;
 
 /**
  * Metodos Getter E Setters dos objetos
  * @return
  */
 
 @Override
 public StreamedContent getArquivoReport() throws Exception {
  super.setNomeRelatorioJasper("report_material");
  super.setNomeRelatorioSaida("report_material");
  super.setListDataBeanCollectionReport(materialController.findList(getClassImp()));
  return super.getArquivoReport();
 }
 
 public Material getObjetoSelecionado() {
  return objetoSelecionado;
 }

 public void setObjetoSelecionado(Material objetoSelecionado) {

  this.objetoSelecionado = objetoSelecionado;
 }
 
 public String getUrl() {
  return url;
 }
 
 public String getUrlFind() {
  return urlFind;
 }

 public void setUrlFind(String urlFind) {
  this.urlFind = urlFind;
 }

 public CarregamentoLazyListForObjeto<Material> getList() throws Exception {
  return list;
 }

 /**
  * Metodos para manipular salvamento, exclusões, editar, novo 
  */
 
 @Override
 public String save() throws Exception {
     objetoSelecionado = materialController.merge(objetoSelecionado);
    
  return "";
 }
 
 @Override
 public void saveNotReturn() throws Exception {
  list.clean();
  objetoSelecionado = materialController.merge(objetoSelecionado);
  list.add(objetoSelecionado);
  objetoSelecionado = new Material();
  sucesso();
 }
 
 @Override
 public void saveEdit() throws Exception {
  saveNotReturn();
 }
 
 
 @Override
 public String novo() throws Exception {
  setarVariaveisNulas();
  return getUrl();
 }
 
 @Override
 public void setarVariaveisNulas() throws Exception {
  list.clean();
  objetoSelecionado = new Material();
 }
 
 @Override
 public String editar() throws Exception {
  list.clean(); 
  return getUrl();
 }
 
 @Override
 public void excluir() throws Exception {
  objetoSelecionado = (Material) materialController.getSession().get(getClassImp(),  objetoSelecionado.getIdMaterial());
  materialController.delete(objetoSelecionado); 
  list.remove(objetoSelecionado);
  objetoSelecionado = new Material();
  sucesso();
 }

 @Override
 protected Class<Material> getClassImp() {
  return Material.class;
 }
 
 @Override
 public String redirecionarFindEntidade() throws Exception {
  setarVariaveisNulas();
  return urlFind;
 }

 @Override
 protected InterfaceCrud<Material> getController() {
  return materialController;
 }
 @Override
 public void consultarEntidade() throws Exception {
   objetoSelecionado = new Material();
   list.clean();
   list.setTotalRegistroConsulta(super.totalRegistroConsulta(), super.getSqlLazyQuery());
 }

 @Override
 public String condicaoAndParaPesquisa() throws Exception {
  return "";
 }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, o problema era 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationFailedException

Não mudei no Jasper Ireport a linguagem do formulario para java, estava groovy.